# PyYAML - is order of a list preserved?

Tags: python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

With following YAML file at *filepath* containing list:

```
nodes:
    - first
    - second
    - third
```

When read this file with pyyaml,

```
config = yaml.load(file(filepath, 'r'))
```

is the order of the **list** always preserved?
In other words, is it guaranteed that it will always true that *config['nodes'][0]* is *'first'* ?

Comment: It will parse the file in order and add items to a list (an ordered data structure), so although I don't know if it's *guaranteed* by the YAML spec, I don't see why it wouldn't be in practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the order of sequences is preserved. In [YAML a sequence](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2802662) (which maps to a python list):

> Represents a collection indexed by sequential integers starting with zero. Example bindings to native types include Perl’s array, Python’s list or tuple, and Java’s array or Vector.

What is not preserved in YAML normally is the order of keys in mappings (although there is of course an order in any serialised form of such a mapping), and such mappings are normally read in as python dicts, which have no ordering in their keys either.

Comment: `which have no ordering in their keys either` - this is [no longer](https://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2020/02/05/dicts-ordered/) the case.